Dynamic tags in Azure Sentinel Incidents
Is it possible to set tags on incidents dynamically based on the content of an alert/incident.
All I've been able to do is create automations with static tags based on conditions, but I don't want to set up a heap of different automations for all the possibilities.

Are you still looking out for an approach. @Rumpleteaser

Yes, it is possible to set tags on incidents dynamically based on the content of an incident.
First approach is using the Analytics under Microsoft Sentinel. Go to Analytics >> Click on scheduled query rule and add a rule logic in KQL as shown below.
Reference Blog for more relevant information on the same.
Here I have added a sample KQL query related to Azure Activity and also included tags under automation rule settings. Once the query condition has been triggered, the tags will be applied dynamically.


Second approach is to go with the Azure sentinel playbooks available under Automation of Microsoft Sentinel.
Create a new playbook with incident trigger and set up an incident according to the requirement as shown below. You can add the conditions under control action to add the tags dynamically.

Reference: Blog for building the analytic rules under Sentinel workspace.

Have you tried the approach given above. @Rumpleteaser
